# pentaho schema workbench connection error with mysql database

Tags: database-connection, pentaho, workbench

on pentaho schema workbench, i want to establish a connection with my mysql database. 
but i get the following error even i added mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar to my drivers : C:\Pentaho\design-tools\schema-workbench.

```
         Erreur lors de la connexion à la Base de données [test] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
         Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

              Error connecting to database: (using class   org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
         Nom de base de donnÃ©e illÃ©gal: 'database_dim '


         org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
         Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

         Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
         Nom de base de donnÃ©e illÃ©gal: 'database_dim '


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2795)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:598)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:71)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:250)
at mondrian.gui.Workbench.connectionButtonActionPerformed(Workbench.java:1288)
at mondrian.gui.Workbench.access$900(Workbench.java:58)
at mondrian.gui.Workbench$11.actionPerformed(Workbench.java:557)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Nom de base de donnÃ©e illÃ©gal: 'database_dim 'at       org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:585)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
... 74 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Nom de   base de donnÃ©e illÃ©gal: 'database_dim '
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
at    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:567)
... 75 more

Nom Serveur hôte       : localhost
Numéro Port           : 3306
Base de données  : database_dim
```

}
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You have a space behind the database schema. "database_dim " instead of "database_dim".

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay, you saved me.

Comment: I'll convert my comment to an answer then :-)

Comment: yes, thank you so much another time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Error connecting to database: (using class   org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
         Nom de base de donnÃ©e illÃ©gal: 'database_dim '
```

There is an extra space behind "database_dim", which is not trimmed from the field by the driver apparently.